# issues with clear Timeout at logout

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a notification alert that shows after 60 seconds of login, the problem is that if someone logout within those 60 seconds. the message still show even if the user is no longer logged-in.

below is what I tried to do to solve this problem, but without success. do I need 
I have tried default export to export `timerId` but since react-native only allows one default export and this happened before this part of the code I could not use default export.
I tried to do export `timerId`; but I got an error saying unresolved variable.

index.js:

```
_myAlert= () => {
    timerId: setTimeout(()=>{
      Alert.alert(
        'Notification',
        'Please set up your user account.'
      );
    }, 60000)
  }
```

drawer.js:

```
onPress={() => {
             clearTimeout(this.timerId);
              this.jumpToSection('Logout');
        }
   }
```

Comment: Is this both code in one file??

Comment: no they are in two different files and directories

Comment: `console.log(this.timerId)` is your timerId correct? It doesn't look like you're referencing the correct timer. You need to store a reference to it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could have a scope problem.

Next link could be help
https://cybmeta.com/var-let-y-const-en-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution where timerhandle is cleared only in componentWillUnmount but the alert is shown only if button is not pressed.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import ClearButton from './src/ClearButton'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.timerHandle = 0;
        this.state = {
            pressed: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => {
            if (!this.state.pressed) {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Notification',
                    'Please set up your user account.'
                );
            }
        }, 60000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.timerHandle) {
            clearTimeout(this.timerHandle);
        }
    }

    onPress() {
        this.setState({ pressed: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ClearButton onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

ClearButton.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class ClearButton extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress.bind(this)}>
                <View style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#0000ff'}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

export default ClearButton;
```

I guess you could also clear the timer in App.js onPress method if you wish not to use this.state.pressed but you should still not remove the clearing in componentWillUnmount.